# How can I use `:keepjump` with `gd`/`gf`/searches?

Tags: vimscript, cursor-motions

I know that plugin that can do it almost certainly exists. Or maybe I could use something like LSP for this. But I want to make my simple command, that will go to file with definition of component / function / class in JS. It's not difficult, because in JS all imports are explicitly, so I wrote this command in my .vimrc

```
autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap gd gd/from<CR>:noh<CR>5lgf
```

1. `gd` = go to definition (first occurrence of symbol)
2. `/from` = find from in this string (because string will be like `import smth from 'filename'`)
3. `:noh` = remove unnecessary highlighting
4. `5l` = skip from word to move to filename
5. `gf` = go file

This works well; it goes to required file.

When I return to my old file, my cursor is on the line with `import`, but I want to remain in the line where I typed `gd`. I heard about `:keepjump` but I don't understand how can I use it here. How can I do this ?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This is already built-in functionality. First use `set include` to add the patterns used for imports, check that vim is detecting them correctly (`:checkpath!`)  and press `[ CTRL-D` or `[D` to display all the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nnoremap gd m':keepjumps normal!gd$Bgf<CR>:noh<CR>
```

`:keepjumps` allows you to perform command-line commands without changing the jumplist, but your mapping uses normal-mode commands and searches. You can run normal-mode commands from the command-line with the `:normal` command, and then you can apply `:keepjumps` to this.

I replaced your search with the normal-mode commands: `$B`, which moves to the same position in a different way: Let me know if this doesn't work in all circumstances and I'll add a slightly more complicated version that preserves more exactly the behaviour of your original version.

Also, because you are using `:keepjumps`, the position immediately before running `gd` is not stored in the jumplist, so when returning with <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> you'd actually be at the jump *before* moving to the position you execute your mapping. To fix this, I use `m'` before running the `:keepjumps normal` command, to manually add the desired cursor position to the jumplist.

Comment: That looks almost perfect! Works with both ' and ". Thank you! Only one small problem = find highlighting isn't disabled after running gd command.

Comment: @moskalenco_a I forgot `gd` would set search highlighting. You should just be able to append `:noh` to the end of the mapping, I think. I’ll edit this into the answer once I’ve had a chance to test it.

Comment: I know about :noh, but can't find where to insert it. But now try this, and looks like it works.

autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap gd m':keepjumps normal!gd$Blgf<CR> :noh<CR>

Thank you!

Comment: Some imporovement. For cases when one import is splitted into multiple lines.

autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap gd m':keepjumps normal!gd<CR>/from<CR>5lgf<CR> :noh<CR>

Answer (score 1):

1. Save cursor position into `:h 'quote` mark. For example,

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim

```
nnoremap <buffer>gd <cmd>let w:curpos = getcurpos()[1:]->insert(bufnr())<CR>
    \gd/\<from\><CR>wgf
    \<cmd>noh<bar>call setpos("'\"", remove(w:, 'curpos'))<CR>
```

2. Make sure cursor position is restored as suggested in `:h restore-cursor`.
3. Note that if option `:set hidden?` is TRUE then buffer contents is preserved in RAM and no `BufRead` event will be fired upon returning to old buffer. You can take this into account by catching `BufWinEnter` *instead of* `BufRead`:

> ~/.vim/vimrc

```
augroup restore_cursor | au!
    autocmd BufWinEnter *
        \   if empty(&buftype)
        \ |     call getpos("'\"")->setpos('.')
        \ | endif
augroup end
```